# Java Spring Data JPA - Long entity chain searching on child to return the whole entity structure

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have quite a long entity chain that looks like the following, it's a one to many relationships at each step :

```
Reference -> DocumentVersion -> CodeSet -> Configuration -> Run
```

I have a requirement to get all Run(s) on a specific date, however, I need to return the entire Reference entity.

Reference.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reference")
public class Reference {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int internalNumber;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id")
    private List<DocumentVersion> documentVersion;

    public List<DocumentVersion> getDocumentVersion() {
        return documentVersion;
    }
    public void setDocumentVersion(List<DocumentVersion> documentVersion) {
        this.documentVersion = documentVersion;
    }
}
```

```
... -> DocumentVersion -> CodeSet -> Configuration -> ...
```

Run.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "run")
public class Run {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int runReference;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date runDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="configuration_reference", nullable=false)
    private Configuration configuration;
}
```

from the controller we call into this function in the service :

```
public Optional<List<Run>> getRunsByDate(String sAnyDate) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        LocalDate anyDate = LocalDate.parse(sAnyDate, formatter);
        return runRepo.findByRunDate(anyDate);
    }
```

Which returns all runs.

When I enable `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug` I can see it generating the SQL for the entire entity chain, is there any way I can access that data and return, or is there another way to get JPA to simply return the Reference?

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: If I have understood right you want to extract al References related, through DocumentVersion -> CodeSet -> Configuration, to a run, right ? If yes, you can do it using ReferenceRepository with a method like "findByDocumentVersion_codeSet_configuration_run_date"

Comment: You can write a query. I don't understand your problem

Comment: @SandeepKumar - no error message is getting shown

Comment: @e.g78 - yes you understood ccorrectly - your suggestion worked perfectly - thanks :)

Comment: I write it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood right you want to extract al References related, through DocumentVersion -> CodeSet -> Configuration, to a run, right ?

If yes, you can do it using ReferenceRepository with a method like

> findByDocumentVersion_codeSet_configuration_run_date